# How to rearrange Data set in Column in DHIS2 form

Tags: dhis2

I have a form section where some data set have Options and also have indicators, how i can do that, like in image below

[image]

In this I have one Data element with name of New Cases having multiple options in Gender and Age agroups and have Data set without any further option.

can you please guide how to design this in DHIS2

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve it but my recommendation would be this:

1. Create a category "Gender", with category options "Male" and "Female".
2. Create a category "Age group", with category options for all the age groups like "<1 y", "1-4y", and so on.
3. Create a category combination "Gender and age group" with those two categories above.
4. Create data elements for the types of case: "General OPD", "Medicine", "Surgery" and so on. Assign the "Gender and age group" category combination to all those data elements.
5. You can create indicators which expressions that summarizes each "field" in the form.
6. Assign all those data elements and indicators to a data set.
7. Create a custom data entry form for that data set and assign each data element and category option combination to the appropriate input fields. You can skip inserting any field in the grayed out input cells. You can insert indicators for the "Total" column fields.